# practising database queries (sql/tsql)

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I wish to refine my skills on t-sql (remote procedure calls etc) and making queries on DB's. I have a macbook and would like to know is there any software i can use to accomplish this? Ideally i would not like to install any software on this computer at all but if i have no choice then so be it.

Comment: thanks for the response guys, any chance i can also practice stored procedures also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). You can create schemas on many types of DB (different versions of SQL Server, MySql, Oracle etc.), practice writing queries, and even send the link to people so they can practice on the same schema/example data as you.

Comment: thanks for the response this is kind of what i was looking for, one problem is you have to create the tables manually, are there examples i can just insert and run queries against?

Comment: No - how would it know what columns there are, what datatypes these columns are, lengths, constraints, keys, everything you'd come up against in a real database. If you're looking for some example data you'd need to install it on a local instance - if so, look up the AdventureWorks database from Microsoft.

Comment: hmm so in order for me to test my queries i would need to create the tables from scratch?

Comment: You should be able to find example schemas on many "learn sql" type sites.

You can probably find countless examples of database schemas on here if you want - search for questions in the SQL tag and you should find some examples pretty quickly (I can't guarantee the quality though, some are pretty poor and that's why they're here asking for help!)

Comment: @godzilla: If you have an example table in the form of formatted text, you could use SQL Fiddle's *Text to DDL* tool to generate DDL and INSERT series automatically.

Comment: @godzilla In response to your recent comment on the your original post - you can practice creating tables, views, functions, stored procedures all with SQL Fiddle.

We forget of course creating good schemas is a fundamental part of learning SQL - it might be a good idea to create your own table schemas to play with.

Comment: @AndriyM Thanks - worth a mention.

Comment: thanks guys much appreciated i will give it all a shot wish me luck!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a place where you can practice making queries without installing software.

http://sqlzoo.net/

Comment: This place is excellent and has full tutorials with hands on exerices